# Trying to install J3DView

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, linux-mint

After entering the following in the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-dev python3-pip
sudo pip3 install cx_Freeze Cython PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate
sudo python3 setup.py install_exe
```

The last command gives me this error:

```
Could not import cx_Freeze. Building executable not possible.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
ImportError: No module named 'Cython'
```

Any ideas why?

I'm using Linux Mint 17.3 'Rosa' Cinnamon 64-bit.

[EDIT]

This problem was a complete mess and I still have no clue what happened before. I have given up trying to get Python to work, as I have found an application that does the same thing as the Python application I was trying to get working. It's such a pain.